# How to find the number density (or count per unit distance ) in the following figures. This illustrates the genomic locations of repeats?

Tags: equation-solving

I have attached herewith a figure wherein there are three different images. In the figure one, every red item is regularly located, and therefore the number density is 15/3 = 5, occurrence of an item every 5 blocks. How can I calculate the same density for the next two figures wherein the second image has distance as a variable, and the third has both distance and the repetitive element being variables.[image: Link to the Image]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Is this a Mathematica question? If so, please include Mathematica code that you have tried out so far.

Comment: Actually, this is a biology relevant question, and I would like to know how mathematically I can approach it. Also I am new to this platform. Thank you

Comment: If you are trying to determine periodicities in longish (or at least not short) genomic sequences, the Wolfram Function Repository function [IrregularPeriodogram](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/IrregularPeriodogram/) has an example in the Applications section. Also see [this Wolfram Community post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1874816) for a couple of approaches.